# How to get document values while validating during a mongoose document update?

Tags: javascript, mongoose

I'm having a problem while trying to run validations with mongoose.
I need to validate a value during an update to be sure that the new value is valid. In my case, I have two fields, a `start` and an `end` field, which means that while updating I need to check if the new `end` value is lower than the current `start` value.

My validation is

```
  period: {
    start: { type: Date, required: true, default: new Date() },
    end: {
      type: Date,
      required: true,
      validate: {
        validator: function (v) {
          return this.period.start < v;
        },
        message: props =>
          `finish date ${props.value} is previous than start date!`,
      },
    },
  },
```

This works fine during creation, but when you try to update it does not work at all. it says that `period` is `null` or `undefined`, if I add on `findOneAndUpdate` the options `{ runValidators: true, context: 'query' }`, then `this` is a mongoose object, but I actually need to access data from the document that I'm trying to validate to check if the original value of `start` is not higher than the new value of `end`.

So I'm wondering how to get the current document during validation?

If for some reason this is impossible, how do I validate during an update? because I need to validate everything whenever it is creating and updating.

I thought about some "workaround" but I'm sure that mongoose has a correct way to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## **You just can't**.

After bumping into the same problem - mongodb doesn't support accessing the updated document during the update. Which means: if you want to use the document validation method during update, you can **only** do it without the other fields.
Which means, you can either validate independently without "this" keyword,
or validate in the update function, or use this walkaround I found:

Send the field/variable you need to verify inside your query(let say in the options object), which would look like:{ runValidators: true, **context**: 'query', start: whatYouNeed }. see [docs](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/validation.html#the-context-option) for reference.
To sum it up:
validator function, inside your model definition:

```
validator:function(value){
if(value<this.options.period.start)do something
}
```

and the update call:

```
findByIdAndUpdate(id,updateObject,{{ runValidators: true, context: 'query', start: 
whatYouNeed }})
```

edit: be careful not to use an arrow function inside the validator, because it will turn "this" into an empty object.